# Content gets hidden when using overflow-x: auto

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm attempting to make a responsive table to allow the user to scroll horizontally at less than 540px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
.dynamic-journey-table{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

}

However at less than 540px the table completely disappears.

```
<portlet-body *ngIf="mediaResults && mediaResults.length > 0 && !loading">
    <div class="dynamic-journey-table">
        <table matSort (matSortChange)="sortMediaResults($event)" class="fill-space light-blue-stripe" style="top: -15px; margin-bottom: 100px;">
            <thead>
```

Not sure if I should set the width of the parent div for the table or not in this case. However that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: We'll need more details... Are there any other media queries or CSS we should know about which could be interfering?  Is the parent's width set to 0?  This would effectively hide the containing table.  Does the `ngif` evaluate to `false` at less than 540px?

Comment: There are no media queries that would interfere here. This is happening even w/ no media query. I set the width of .dynamic-journey-table and this still happens. The *ngIf doesn't evaluate to false at less than 540px.

Comment: Can you give details around what exactly you are experiencing when you look in Chrome's dev tools? Is the DOM node present at the resolution in question? Have you debugged the DOM nodes' CSS to see what the difference is that is causing it to disappear? Without a running example it is hard to give you an answer (esp. since you stated that it has nothing to do with your media query). My best guess is that there is some other overall media query that is being ran causing the issue. You should be able to tell this using Chrome's tools tho.